# Raspberry Pi red light

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ connected to an external USB disk, a Seagate Portable 1 Tb (no external power source).

Everything is working fine, but when the disk is writing/reading data, the red light (power) blinks, sometimes. But I don't have any power loss, or corrupted data.

I've tested with 3 different power sources:

1) a generic one, that blinks (5V 3A)

2) my original charger from Galaxy S4 (5V 2A) does the same

3) a Galaxy Tab 3 charger (5V 2A) the red light keeps always off

Since the original Samsung chargers are trustable, I believe that my external HD is using too much power? But if this is true, why Raspberry keeps on and I got no corrupted data?

The red light blinking but everything working fine is a real problem? Or can damage it in some weeks or months? Maybe I need consider stop using an external disk?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the led is not blinking to show disk activity?

Comment: Yes, the disk activity is the green light. Red light is the power light. As I read over the internet, the red light needs to be on always.

Comment: Ok, given that, I would say that it is only a matter of lock that you have not yet experienced data loss/corruption. I would suggest adding an external power source or if that is not possible putting a powered hub between the Pi and disk.

Comment: so you still have no issues with the LED blinking ? corrupt data on HDD ?

Comment: In the end, I've changed the external HD by a SSD (sata to usb cable). No more issues and no data corruption. My actual config is a MicroSD 32 Gb for the OS, a 128 GB SSD for data. No more blinking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting):

> Red power LED is blinking
>   A blinking red power LED indicates problems
>   with the power supply. On model A and B, it is hard-wired to the 3.3V
>   power supply rail. If it is blinking, as one user has reported[1](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting) it
>   means the 5V power supply is dropping out. Use a different power
>   supply.
>
> On model B+ (and presumably also the A+), the circuit has been
>   improved to give a much more reliable warning of poor power quality.
>   The red power LED is wired to an APX803 supervisor[2] which kicks in
>   when the 5V power supply drops below 4.63V[3]. If it does, the LED
>   will blink. Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

Answer (score 6):

The raspberry pi 3B+ also seems to use the red pwr led as a error indicator !

I have a SD card (Apacer 16GB) that came with the pi, preloaded with noobs 245.
This card however does NOT work with the pi. When using this card: red pwr led on, NO green light, but after a few secs the RED led starts flashing a code every few seconds: 4x long, 3x short than on again.

So NO Power problem (5A supply, steady at 4.97v) !
This flashing red led only happens with this SD card, other SD cards boots OK....

Comment: Same here, with raspbian it was just dead, nothing flashing. Using ubuntu mate image I got the red led blinking thing. Then I tried another sdcard and it works fine. Luckily for me I bought 10x of the card that doesn't work...

Comment: I had the same. I didn't change the SD but replaced contents with the latest official NOOBS and the card started to work.